# How to stop a PHP function called in a closed browser tab?

Tags: php, apache, localhost, exit, wampserver

I have a PHP code that parses a website recursively, and saves necessary info into the database.

My current function is about to parse 500 pages. However, I noticed I have an error after starting the "crawling". Now I need to stop, empty the database and call the function again.

But the function is not stopping :D

I closed the tab, I tried calling `exit("");` from another tab, but this monster won't stop !

I'm using WAMPServer in localhost, will it help to Stop All Services and start again? Will it continue crawling, or will everything stop when I restart Apache ?

Comment: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Comment: @Linblow great! So this is currently false, and I should make it true in my script, right? **edit:** it doesn't work :/

Comment: ignore_user_abort is for command-line processing, and the default is to abort on loss of terminal so that won't help here.

Comment: You shouldn't be starting such a task from a web page in the first place. This is a long running task which has nothing to do with answering a web request. It should be started manually from the command line or as some part of daemon or queue worker. In either case, you can stop it with a task manager, like any other process on your computer.

Comment: @DigitalChris It's not only for command-line processing.
CengizFrostclaw This is a kind of bug in PHP.. You need to send content to the output buffer and clear it in your loop to get the expected behavior. Try this code http://pastebin.com/ZRixXC6i paste it in test.php for example. Run the script test.php in a tab, and then open counter.txt in a new tab from the same directory. Keep refreshing counter.txt and you'll see it keeps incrementing whether the script test.php has been aborted or not. Then retry with ignore_user_abort to false. This time, it'll stop incrementing once it's aborted.

Comment: Here is another example http://pastebin.com/utEYd55k create test.php and run it in a tab. A file "connection_closed" will be created once the connection is aborted.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your task manager an stop php process,it will stop the script,or trying stoping apache service on wamp panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ignore_user_abort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) and or [`connection_status`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-status.php).

In both cases, you need to send something to the output so that those functions work properly.

Example 1: http://pastebin.com/kb9mu2pt

Example 2: http://pastebin.com/nbhXZNGa

To come back to your problem, you'd use [`ignore_user_abort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) and set it to `false`. In the loop where you're parsing pages: you'd need to add the 3 instructions to write/send something to the output so that the functions work well (see examples).